# CameraSource.Photos is opening pwa camera instead of gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

`Camera.getPhoto()` with source Photos is opening `pwa` camera instead of showing gallery in my android phone. I also tried using `Prompt` as a source but the result was same.

```
accessGallery() {
  return Camera.getPhoto({
    resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
    source: CameraSource.Photos,
    quality: 100,
  });
}
```

Versions:

ionic --version is 6.10.1

@capacitor/android: ^1.5.2

@capacitor/core: ^1.5.2

Comment: What’s your capacitor version?

Comment: My cap version is 1.5.2.

Comment: update to 2.3.0